# django request with two date field

Tags: python, django, date, filter, request

I am trying to attempt a request with a filter on a combination of a date, and an integer which represent a year, and I encounter some trouble doing it.

Here is my model :

```
class Exemple(models.Model):
    date_field = models.DateField()
    year_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is the request which work :

```
exs = Exemple.objects.extra(where=["DATE(date_field, '+' || year_field|| ' years') < DATE('now') OR date_field is NULL"])
```

I want to do the exact same request using only the django ORM,
I tried this (which didn't work)

```
from django.db.models import F
import datetime
exs = Exemple.objects.filter(date_field__lt=datetime.timedelta(days=-365*F('year_field'))+datetime.datetime.today().year)
```

I think the problem is that F() isn't yet a value at the moment timedelta get called

Thanks by advance for any solution, or idea that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the problem. You can't do complex calculations like that with just the ORM. However, you might be able to take advantage of the `__year` lookup to simplify the math:

```
Exemple.objects.filter(date_field__year__lt=F('year_field'))
```

Anything more complex than that, though, and you have to use `extra`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tried to concentrate only on the year :
exs = Exemple.objects.filter(date_field__year__lt=0-F('year_field')+datetime.datetime.today().year)

But get an error : "Join on field 'date_verif' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?"

Anyway, I have to take care of the whole date, because months and days are important here, so I think I'll do it with extra, but since I'll have to deploy it to another DB system, I'll have to adapt it...

thanks again

Comment: So, after a brief research, I find this : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10911